# WinXP 64bit cannot see files on dfs

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-xp

I have

Server1
Win2008 Storage Server
Running DFS
Access-based enumeration - off
Offline settings - disabled

Workstation1
WinXP SP3 32bit

Workstation2
WinXP SP2 64bit

I have a shared folder on Server1 on the DFS share.
Workstation1 can see all files and folders. Workstation2 does not. I have tested with multiple WinXP 64bit PCs and the same files across these machines do not show up. Going directly to the files via the address bar works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is prevented/avoided by going to the UNC share via ip address.

Answer (score 1):

WinXP 64-bit has many problems. Stick with 32-bit or upgrade to Vista or Windows 7 if you want/need 64-bit.